# How to reach for the header-section:before from the JS for styling

Tags: javascript, if-statement, styling

I want to change the background color in the header-section:before depending on the value.

this is the html part

```
<section class="header-section" id="main-header"> 
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header"> 
            <h1>
                <span id="temperature"></span>
                <span id="todays-img"></span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <h2><span id="city-name"></span></h2>
        <p><span id="description"></span></p>
        <div class="sunrise-sunset">
            <p class="sun-child"><span id="sunrise"></span></p>
            <p class="sun-child"><span id="sunset"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

in the css the background color is defined under:

```
.header-section:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #8AB7F8, #D6E4F9);
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%/0 0 50% 50%;
    transform: scalex(1.5);
}
```

and this is what I have in the JS, which is changing the color of the header-section , but not the header-section:before

```
    const headerBackground = document.getElementById('main-header');

    const checkTemperature = () => {
      if (filteredForecast[0].main.temp < 0) {
        headerBackground.style.backgroundColor = '#BDCBF5';
      }
```

So now it is changing the color of the header-section and not the header-section:before. How can I reach for the header-section:before in the JS since I can't get it from the html by document.getElementById.

Comment: I am not sure if you can select it; you can over-write its content with more CSS but that was about it I thought.

Comment: If you want a fun hack, you could insert a style right after the pseudo-element, and when you want to reset or change it, delete and insert the new styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the style of pseudo elements directly. The only way to change it, is to retrieve the stylesheet and change the relevant rule. Here's a snippet that may be a base for further scripting (removed html to present a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Note that in the initial css, the `background` property is set to 'black'.

Also check [this JsFiddle](https://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/ehd2710f).

```js
// find the stylesheet (in the SO context, it's the first stylesheet)
const styleElem = document.styleSheets[0];

// be conservative, check everything
if (styleElem) {
  // retrieve the rules of the stylesheet
  const ruleSet = styleElem.cssRules ? styleElem.cssRules : styleElem.rules;
  
  if (ruleSet) {
    // retrieve the .header-section:before rule
    const headerSectionRule = [...ruleSet].find(rule => 
      rule.selectorText.startsWith(".header-section::before"));
      //                                           ^ note '::'

    if (headerSectionRule && headerSectionRule.style) {
      // found the rule, now set the background style
      headerSectionRule.style.background = 
        "linear-gradient(45deg, #8AB7F8, #D6E4F9)";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.header-section:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  /* Note: initially black */
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%/0 0 50% 50%;
  transform: scalex(1.5);
}
```

```html
<section class="header-section" id="main-header">
<!-- removed for simplicity -->
</section>
```